# Having a fork match the original repo when the original master branch can't be merged in?

Tags: git, version-control, github

The related questions that SO offer me only answer simple cases that can be solved with a pull - however, that doesn't work well, as you'll see below.

There's a repository I've forked, with just a `master` branch, and I've forked it, and I've worked in both my `master`, and a new branch of my own, `rw-style`. The owner of the forked repository's committed some of my changes but not others; the black dots on the top right below represent commits from both my `master` and `rw-style` branches.

[image]

I'm aware using the fork queue is not a good idea, so I'm staying away from it. Using `git pull` does work, but it creates a conflict that I would then need to resolve, and it also results in duplicate history for my `master` branch, and that doesn't look particularly pretty.

I don't know any other solutions right now, so I'm currently considering just creating a patch from two commits that I haven't yet pushed, deleting my fork, creating it again from the original, and then applying my patches on top of it.

Is that the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rebase your fork on to master, via:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

(while in the fork branch).  Alternatively you could also reset --hard your fork branch to your master branch, then cherry-pick every commit from your fork branch back in (but the rebase will be wayyy less work unless you're only forked by a few commits).

Once you've done that, you should be able to just merge your forked branch on to the master branch, as a fast-forward merge (no merge commits or anything).  However, doing either of the above will mess up all of your hashes in your fork branch, so don't do this unless you're sure nothing else is referencing the fork branch.

Comment: Sorry, bit confused there. I've never worked with rebases before. When I tried the command, I was told "Current branch master is up to date.". Not too sure about which branch you're referencing to as the forked one and the master one.

Comment: @a2h: rebase, when given one argument, attempts to rebase the current branch onto that argument. I believe that in your case, what you actually want to do is add the original project as a remote: `git remote add start <url>`, fetch its current state: `git fetch start`, and then rebase onto *that*: `git rebase start/master`. (I've called the original pre-fork repo "start" so that it doesn't look like origin.) Presumably the `origin` remote in your current repo is the github forked project, not the original one, so `master` is indeed up-to-date with `origin/master`.

Comment: @a2h: However: if there are conflicts with an attempted merge, there will also be conflicts with an attempted rebase. It's possible that you could alleviate this by using `git rebase -i` (interactive), and removing lines for commits whose content is already in the original repo's master.

Comment: Ah. There wasn't any conflicts, so that seemed to have worked out.